# what does the 'r' prefix of sequential evaluation strategies of Haskell stand for?

Tags: haskell

Functions are often prefixed with `r` in the [basic sequential evaluation strategies](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.0.6/docs/Control-Seq.html#g:3)

- `r0`
- `rseq`
- `rdeepseq`

What does the 'r' prefix of in Haskell stand for?

Comment: "reduce"? Which, I think, is used as a synonym for "evaluate" when talking about lambda calculus (e.g [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction_strategies)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it stands for **result** from what I've read in the book [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell: Techniques for Multicore and Multithreaded Programming](https://books.google.com/books?id=iSoRAAAAQBAJ&dq=what%20is%20rseq%20haskell)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it stands for "run" or "runEval", which may have to do with the fact that *r0*, *rpar*, *rseq*, *rdeepseq* and related strategies operate in the Eval monad, which uses *runEval* to extract the value (execute the strategy).